# What are the software and hardware requirements for using agora?

Tags: agora.io

What are the different uses of agora, and the hardware and software requirements. How it can be implemented in apps. Maximum number of users possible at a time in a single video call.

Answer (score 0):

Agora has a section of their website dedicated to various use cases.

Social: https://www.agora.io/en/social/
Gaming: https://www.agora.io/en/gaming/
Retail: https://www.agora.io/en/retail-ecommerce/
Education: https://www.agora.io/en/education/

Regarding hardware requirements, the minimum specs is wifi, a microphone, and a video camera (for video SDK). For software, any device that can run Android 4.1 or later, iOS 8.0 or newer, Windows XP (SP3), and MacOSX or later. Full spec: https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/platform

With regard to maximum number of user, it depends on whether you are in Boradcast or Communications mode. Broadcast mode supports up to 1m audience members with up to 17 broadcasters. In communications mode it limits you to 10k in Voice and 7 for Video. Full Spec: https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/capacity